# What to do if Windows XP install complains about not finding file XXX.dl_

Tags: windows, windows-xp, installation, windows-installation, windows-server-2003

I've ran into a problem recently trying to do a repair install of a Windows XP SP3. By the time it was copying the files, it complained about not being able to find file cmprops.dl_ on the Windows CD.

I'm posting this question here with the answer below to anyone having the same problem!

According to MS KB818464, these files could present problem:

```
Cmprops.dl_
Licwmi.dl_ 
Mmfutil.dl_ 
Servereps.dl_
```

Comment: As per [MS KB818464](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/818464):

During the installation, when you receive a dialog asking for any of those files:

 1. Press Shift-F10 to bring up a command prompt 
 2. Run `esentutl /p %windir%\security\database\secedit.sdb`
 3. Go to `cd %windir%\security`
 4. Delete file `edb.log` (it might be edb00001.log or something like)
 5. Close command prompt and press retry - it should work now!

Comment: The comment above is the answer, I just can't post it right now (have to wait for 8h before answering my own question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per MS KB818464:

During the installation, when you receive a dialog asking for any of those files:

1. Press Shift-F10 to bring up a command prompt
2. Run `esentutl /p %windir%\security\database\secedit.sdb`
3. Go to `cd %windir%\security`
4. Delete file `edb.log` (it might be edb00001.log or something like)
5. Close command prompt and press retry - it should work now!

Comment: KB818464 is no longer on the Microsoft website, but luckily the Wayback Machine has it https://web.archive.org/web/20121102132354/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/818464